# Convert a SVG to a PNG/JPEG without using canvas in a serverless function

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, serverless, vercel

I have a serverless function which returns a SVG based on a text sent as a query parameter.

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const { yourName } = req.query;

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml");

  const svg = `
    <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 600 400" width="600" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <style>
            .title {
              font-size: 10vh;
              font-weight: regular;
              background-color: #ffddff;
            }
          </style>
            
          <p class="title">Hello ${yourName}</p> 
          
        </div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
  `;

  res.send(svg);

};
```

As an example, when I call `/api?yourName=world`, it returns me the following SVG;

[image: hello world by a serveless api]

(Deployed URL: [https://vercel-test-ruddy.vercel.app/api?world](https://vercel-test-ruddy.vercel.app/api?yourName=world))

#### What I need?

I need to return the SVG as an image (PNG/JPEG).
So, the my function would look like,

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const { yourName } = req.query;

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");

  const svg = `
    <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 600 400" width="600" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <style>
            .title {
              font-size: 10vh;
              font-weight: regular;
              background-color: #ffddff;
            }
          </style>
            
          <p class="title">Hello ${yourName}</p> 
          
        </div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
  `;

  res.send( svgToPng(svg) );

};

svgToPng = (svg) => {
   // not defined
}
```

#### Did I refer other SO questions?

Yes. There are few questions regarding converting SVG to PNG:

[Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1)  
[How to Exporting SVG as PNG format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121992/how-to-exporting-svg-as-png-format?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Almost every answer talks about converting SVG to canvas and then canvas to PNG. And also answers are much older too. Can we do it without using a canvas?

In my project I actually don't have a html `document`, I have only one single `.js` file (As I know we need HTML5 to use canvas).

#### Notes

I have used using [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) to deploy my serverless function which is;

Deployed at: [https://vercel-test-ruddy.vercel.app/api?yourName=YOUR_NAME_HERE](https://vercel-test-ruddy.vercel.app/api?yourName=world) 
GitRepo: https://github.com/tharindusathis/vercel-test

Comment: To convert SVG to bitmap it needs to be rasterized ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation ) Canvas is only a pixel store while encoding image file via `toBlob` or `toDataURL` . Rasterization is extremely complex (if you want quality), and would be agonisingly slow in JS without a GPU (or equivalent processing power). Encoding a bitmap to an img file is easy. There are likely many JS open source encoders you can use. Rasterize SVG consult vercel documentation ask What type of back end? Is there a SVG rasterize component?

Comment: To add to what @Blindman67 said, here you don't even need *just* an svg renderer, you need an HTML + CSS renderer (to render the foreignObject). The only SVG renderers I know of that are able to do this are web browsers.  What does "In my project I actually don't have a html document," mean? Where is this project ran from? If only from the server, then you could maybe consider running an headless browser like PhantomJS, though I don't know if vercel can do something like that (I really don't know Vercel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to deal with this that I have found so far is by using a headless chrome and getting a screenshot. As an example by using `puppeteer` I could get a screenshot of the viewport like follows,

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

let yourName = 'world'

const svg = `
    <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 600 400" width="600" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <style>
            .title {
              font-size: 10vh;
              font-weight: regular;
              background-color: #ffddff;
            }
          </style>
            
          <p class="title">Hello ${yourName}</p> 
          
        </div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
  `;

await page.setViewport({ width: 2048, height: 1170 });
await page.setContent(svg);

console.log(await page.content());
await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
await browser.close();
```

Then it will be easy to send the `png` as the response.

Comment: This is the one I've been looking for for 3 days. This is the real solution to the foreignObject tainted canvas problem.

Comment: What's the performance of this like? Do you launch and close the browser for every request to prevent memory leak?